# Are there other ways to apply a function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, function

If I want to use `real()` or `abs()` on some variable or vector like x, I have to write `real(x)` or `abs(x)`. In Mathematica someone can use either `Re[x]` or `Re@x`. What is the equivalent of `@` in Matlab? 
I mean using `@` is a shorthand notation for `[]` in Mathematica. Is there such a shorthand notation in Matlab?

Comment: I am not not think such a shorthand notation exists in matlab. Some functions are defined to have a space before arguments like `clear var1 var2` (equivalent to `clear('var1','var2')`) and `sym` can be called as `syms var1 var2` instead of `var1 = sym('var1'); var2 = sym('var2');`. Anyway, the `fcn(in1, in2,...)` syntax is an extremely simple syntax and is superior to most when it comes to readability, so I do not complain ;)

Comment: I don't understand why you would want abs@x instead of abs(x). I think the readability is very good, and it's not exactly hard to write either...

Comment: @RobertP. I prefer `real@abs(x)` to `real(abs(x))`. The former is more readable.

Comment: @yashar. Yes you can prefer, but it is in no way more "readable". Someone with no knowledge of this syntax can think you are executing the function `real@abs` on the input value `x` ... while anyone with no programming knowledge but having been to school long enough to use a calculator knows the order of precedence of the parenthesis, and will assume (rightly) that you are executing the function `real` on the result of the function `abs` with input `x`. In fact, the parenthesis syntax is so wide spread that it is often used to explain more complex syntax (like the one you propose) to novices.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers states; no, there is no short-hand notation similar to the ones you find in Mathematica. However, if you use the same combinations of functions often, you can create anonymous function handles that might improve the readability.

```
combinedfun = @(x) myfun1(myfun2(x))
```

or, if you want combinations of built-in functions:

```
absreal = @(x) abs(real(x))
```

In a real project I would not use anonymous functions like these, as there is not control of input arguments etc., but it might be handy if you want to do some calculations on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arrayfun` which needs a function to be applied on each element in `x`

Something like following :

```
arrayfun( @(y)abs(y), x )
```

However for simpler function simply use it on entire vector/variable/element :

`abs(x)`

Comment: I mean using `@` is a shorthand notation for `[]` in Mathematica. Is there such a shorthand notation in Matlab?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @CapeCode If you have one relevant please post one

Answer (score 1):

There is no general shorthand notation for function input. But if your input arguments are strings then you can just use space to separate the function and its input arguments. So

```
strcat('a', 'b')
```

is same as

```
strcat a b
```

It cannot be used if the arguments are store in variables.

Comment: This is the right answer and the only shortcut to the `(...)` assignation, but you should be clearer in your answer that "**NO. There is no global shorthand notation for function input**". The only shortcut you can use is when your input variables are string, then explaining as you did.